# Last Error Stream Component Fatal error. Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL in AWS DMS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, google-cloud-sql, aws-dms, logical-replication

I created a replication task in AWS DMS to take data from GCP Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL DB) to AWS RDS (PostgreSQL DB), both endpoints have a succesful status when are tested, but when the replication task was running I got the following message:

> Last Error Stream Component Fatal error. Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

Somebody got this error before?
Thanks, everybody.

I want to make it work. I have successfully created other replication tasks. The only difference is that this one wasn't set up with an exposed internet connection; it uses a VPC connection. I don't know if this fact has any influence.